# Make a parent div independent of parent divs with CSS

Tags: html, css

```
.cat_p{
    float:left; 
    margin-right:3px; 
    margin-bottom: 1px;}
.cat_p a {
    background: #00A1E0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 1px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
} 
.cat_p a:hover{
    background:  #666; 
    color:#fff;
}
```

This is the code I use to display categories and tags for a post for articles on Wordpress. This works perfectly well on the homepage while on another page(single.php), the code doesn't work properly because the links appear blue in colour which makes it impossible to differentiate category div's background and text.
I checked the code above but can't find any problems. I'd like to know if there's a way I could make the category div independent of the divs above since they might have a problem.

Comment: can you create a generic example of what the problem is on a JSFiddle? I think i may know what the issue is, i just need to see the context of the code.

Comment: Its a whole wordpress theme + wordpress. Can I do that on JSFiddle?

Comment: no, recreate a generic example of the code then. a small one.

Comment: i tried recreating but i dunno why it works fine. the situation could be explained completely only on wordpres.. am really sorry, man

Answer (score 1):

If the CSS is not working in other pages but the homepage means that other piece of CSS is overriding it. Try and look for a specific "id" or "class" of that page to apply that CSS. Normally I would go for a class in the body, then do:

```
.home,
.single-post {

    .cat_p{
        float:left; 
        margin-right:3px; 
        margin-bottom: 1px;}
    .cat_p a {
        background: #00A1E0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding: 1px 7px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    } 
    .cat_p a:hover{
        background:  #666; 
        color:#fff;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. Still the same problem. Actually I tried pasting `<div class="categories">` in different divs and found that it displayed properly on divs prior to `.single_post`, but when I tried to add the categories classes in single_post, it still doesn;t solve the problem.

Comment: Just now I tried editing `#content_box` by adding `#content_box a{color:#FFF;}` which makes all the links on the page including category. But, I just want the category links to be white. I am not able to add `cat_p` under content_box. It doesn't work.

Comment: My only advise is to use the browser inspector to see what CSS is being applied to the elements and create your own CSS copying the same selector with your new properties. Make sure your custom CSS goes at the end, and also try what I said before: an unique class or ID will help. Good luck!

Comment: A last resource could be adding an !important to override all links of that selector #content_box a{color:#FFF !important;}

Comment: Thanks man. Anyways, I got it to work. Added the classes like this - `#content_box .tags_p` It just worked. But, can you help me with another thing?

Comment: When I add `font-size:70%` to `cat_p a` it reduces the font-size but the div cat_p doesn't reduce in size. Can you help me regarding that?